# Background of the ListTile is overflowing in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

With this code the background of the ListTile is getting out of the container. I coloured it red. Where am I going wrong?

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Container(
                  height: 400,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: contentList.length,
                    prototypeItem: const ListTile(
                      style: ListTileStyle.list,
                      title: Text("jhgjhgj"),
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        tileColor: Colors.red,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        title: Text(contentList[index]),
                      );
                    },
                  ))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is an open issue regarding the same that ListTile color getting out of the parent view/specified constraints when the ListTile is wrapped using the Container widget with the background color as mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86584).*

Now to fix your issue (as a workaround), you can wrap the ListTile with the Material widget as:

```
return Material(
                    child: ListTile(
                      tileColor: Colors.red,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      title: Text(contentList[index]),
                    ),
                  );
```

Online demo: https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-z31s06na31t0?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart

Complete answer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Container(
              height: 400,
              color: Colors.grey,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: contentList.length,
                prototypeItem: const ListTile(
                  style: ListTileStyle.list,
                  title: Text("jhgjhgj"),
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Material(
                    child: ListTile(
                      tileColor: Colors.red,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      title: Text(contentList[index]),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using ListView.builder which provides the capability  of scrolling
SingleChildScrollView might not be necessary in this case.
here is the updated code

```
body: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
child: Container(
height: 400,
color: Colors.grey,
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: contentList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      tileColor: Colors.red,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      title: Text(contentList[index]),
    );
  },
),))
```